# How to filter from list of collection using multiple conditions

Tags: java, filter, stream, reduce, predicate

How do I compare from a list of collection and check whether or not specific compound conditions (&& not ||) are matched using minimum code?

Example, I want to validate if the startDateObj=2019-08-27, timeCode=A and endDateObj=2019-08-28, timeCode=D both exists in the response list simultaneously.

I've got the following classes

```
ResponseVo {
    List<DateTimeVo> dateTimeObj;
}

DateTimeVo {
    String dateObj;
    List<TimeVo> timeList;
}

TimeVo {
    String code;
    String displayInformation;
}
```

Sample output

```
{
    "dateTimeObj": [
        {
            "dateObj": "2019-08-27",
            "timeList": [
                {
                    "code": "A",
                    "displayInformation": "Do A Act"
                },
                {
                    "code": "B",
                    "displayInformation": "Do B Act"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "dateObj": "2019-08-28",
            "timeList": [
                {
                    "code": "C",
                    "displayInformation": "Do C Act"
                },
                {
                    "code": "D",
                    "displayInformation": "Do D Act"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Currently, I have implemented it by calling optional post every filter & find first which is looking very untidy & cumbersome.

Comment: Maybe you should show us how you have done it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways one could do this. If the main issue is that the code looks untidy, I would suggest factoring out the filtering predicate into its own method. Then it's just a question of calling [`Stream.anyMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-) with that predicate. For example:

```
public class ResponseVo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ResponseVo response = ... // Obtain response

        boolean anyMatch = response.dateTimeObj
            .stream().anyMatch(dtvo -> exists(dtvo, "2019-08-27", "A"));
    }

    List<DateTimeVo> dateTimeObj;

    private static boolean exists(DateTimeVo dtvo, 
        String date, String code) {
        return dtvo.dateObj.equals(date) && 
            dtvo.timeList.stream().anyMatch(tvo -> tvo.code.equals(code));
    }
}
```

Comment: the only restriction with this is I have to invoke stream twice once for StartDateObject and timeCode and another for endDateObject & timeCode. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a combination of `Predicate`, creating collection of predicates easy to maintain and then apply all of them in the following way:

```
@Test
public void filterCollectionUsingPredicatesCombination(){

    List<Predicate<MyObject>> myPredicates = new ArrayList<Predicate<MyObject>>();
    myPredicates.add(myObject -> myObject.myString.startsWith("prefix"));
    myPredicates.add(myObject -> myObject.myInstant.isBefore(Instant.now()));        
    myPredicates.add(myObject -> myObject.myInt > 300);

    List<MyObject> result = myData.stream() // your collection
      .filter(myPredicates.stream().reduce(x->true, Predicate::and)) // applying all predicates
      .collect(Collectors.toList());

    assertEquals(3, result.size()); // for instance
}
```

Comment: will try this, the intent is to check if StartDateObject & startTimeCode and endDateObject & endTimeCode both exists. Wondering if I use reduce would it be possible to achieve the same?